# Acrobat javascript: deletePagesでの「この操作は許可されていません」エラー

Tags: javascript, pdf

### 前提事項：実行環境

OS：Windows7 SP1
Acrobat：Acrobat Reader XI

### 状況

現在、PDFのページを削除する処理をPDF埋め込みのjavascriptで実現することを試みています。
そのため、[Adobe Acrobat XI + JavaScript例文辞典](http://www.openspc2.org/reibun/AcrobatXI/)様の[「指定ページを削除する」](http://www.openspc2.org/reibun/AcrobatXI/javascript/page/011/index.html)ページを参考にさせていただいております。

しかし、上記ページのサンプル(sample.pdf)をうまく動かすことができておりません。
（ボタンを押すと２ページ目が削除されるはずだが、削除されない）
Acrobat Reader付属のJavaScriptデバッガで確認したところ、以下のエラーが表示されておりました。
○実行時エラー

> RaiseError: この操作は許可されていません Doc.deletePages:1:Field ボタン:Mouse Up  ===>
> この操作は許可されていません

---

同様に、Acrobat Reader 付属のJavaScriptデバッガ上で、以下コードを実行したところ、同様にエラーが出ております。
○実行Script

```
this.deletePages(1);
```

○エラー

> RaiseError: この操作は許可されていません Doc.deletePages:1:Console undefined:Exec
> ===> この操作は許可されていません

### 質問事項

上記エラーについて、どのようにしたら回避できるでしょうか。
セキュリティの問題に見受けられたため、以下の通り設定を変更して試行しましたが、状況に変化はありません。
○修正した設定
■設定＞Javascript
・メニュー項目のJavaScript実行権限を有効にする オフ→オン
・グローバルオブジェクトセキュリティポリシーを有効にする オン→オフ
■設定＞セキュリティ
・変更なし
■設定＞セキュリティ（拡張）
・拡張セキュリティを有効にする　オン→オフ

アドバイスよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[`deletePages()` のリファレンス](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat11_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.89.458.html)に以下の記述があります。（斜体は原文ママ）

> Beginning with version 6.0, this method deletes *spawned* pages from within Adobe Reader for documents with forms usage rights enabled.

試しにAcrobat上でページテンプレートを定義しておき、[`this.getTemplate('hoge').spawn()`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat11_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.89.1221.html) を実行するボタンを配置してみると、AcrobatやAdobeReader上でこのボタンを押して作られたページは `deletePages()` で削除することができました。しかしやはり普通のページは削除できませんでした。

リファレンスの記述と一致していることを考えると、回避するのは難しいように思います。